# Cannot Load Lightning Out in Firefox

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, service-cloud-console, locker-service, lightning-out

I have run into a large blocker regarding the use of Lightning Out to inject a Lightning component into a Visualforce page. I have used the method outlined in the documentation [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_visualforce.htm) in order to load a Lightning component in the classic service console.

The code I am using to inject the component is below:

```
<apex:page standardController="Case" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">

    <apex:slds />
    <apex:includeLightning />
    <apex:includeScript value="/support/console/40.0/integration.js"/>

    <style>
        .slds-form-element__label {
            font-size: 0.8125rem !important;
        }
    </style>
    <body class="slds-scope">
        <!-- Page div used to inject Lightning component -->
        <div id="assetManagerDiv"></div>
    </body>
    
    <!-- Script that uses the Lightning javascript library to inject a lightning component into the VF page div -->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            // Script to inject Lightning component into the Visualforce page
            $Lightning.use("c:AttachAssetToCaseEditorApp", function() {
                $Lightning.createComponent("c:AttachAssetToCaseEditorCmp",
                                            {
                                                "tabId" : '{!$CurrentPage.parameters.Id}'
                                            },
                                            "assetManagerDiv",
                                            function(component) {});
            });
        }());
    </script>
    
</apex:page>
```

I have used this method many times before and it has worked successfully. However, when I try to load the Lightning component in the Firefox browser I receive the following error in the browser console and the Lightning component will not load at all:

> SecurityError: The operation is insecure - aura_proddebug.js:23749
>
> TypeError: $A.initAsync is not a function -
> lightning.out.delegate.js:126:10

This is only happening in Firefox. It is working fine in the Chrome browser. I am using the current 55.0.3 64-bit version of Firefox.

Is there some issue with Firefox and Lightning Out that is currently happening? I am not sure how to figure out what is causing this issue.

Comment: Did u make sure c:AttachAssetToCaseEditorApp extends="ltng:outApp"?

Comment: @RaviJayaramappa Yes it does extend. Otherwise, I don't think it would work in Chrome either. I am looping back around to this issue because I am experiencing it again now.

Comment: did you added dependency in your app <aura:dependency resource="c:AttachAssetToCaseEditorApp"/>

Comment: please include the lightning app and component codes.

Comment: @DanielFuller Please provide the complete markup, controller code for your lightning components to repro this issue. A simpler repro, if possible, would be easier to diagnose the issue. Also, please log a Salesforce case to help you track the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution for this issue. Somehow, there was an issue in the Firefox browser cache that was conflicting with Lightning Out. I cleared my Firefox browser cache and that resolved the issue. I'm not sure what in the cache was the culprit, however.